# Как сделать, чтобы моя функция set_checkpoints() корректно обрабатывала текстовый файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, обработка-данных

У меня есть текстовый файл `data.txt`:

```
яблоко
банан
абрикос
яблоко
апельсин
апельсин
мандарин 
абрикос
абрикос
абрикос
абрикос
абрикос
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы после обработки файла `data.txt`  функцией `set_checkpoints()` на выходе получался файл `save.txt`:

```
//А//яблоко//А//   
//А//банан//А// 
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//яблоко//А//
//А//апельсин//А//
//А//апельсин//А// 
//А//мандарин//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
```

Но в результате у меня получается вот что:

```
//А//яблоко//А//
//А//банан//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
яблоко
//А//апельсин//А//
апельсин
//А//мандарин//А// 
абрикос
абрикос
абрикос
абрикос
абрикос
```

Решение:
Нужно сделать так, чтобы функция при нахождении нужного слова из массива, продолжил поиск данного слова до конца файла, а не прерывался на первом же совпадении и переходил бы к следующему слову. В итоге у меня получается, что он находит из массива `fruits` совпадение со словом из текстового файла, отмечает его чекпойтами и переходит к поиску следующего слова из массива. Как сделать так, чтобы функция работала корректно?

Вот мой код:

```
import re

path = 'data.txt' # input data
save = 'save.txt' # output data

def open_read(path): # функция открывает и считывает файл
    file = open(path, 'r')
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    #print(content)
    return content


Fruits = ['яблоко','банан','абрикос','апельсин','мандарин'] # массив ключевых слов

n=len(Fruits) # определение размера массива Fruits

def set_checkpoints(content): # функция устанавливает checkpoints
    for i in range(n):
        find = re.compile(Fruits[i])
        res = find.search(content)
        #lenght = len(find.findall(content)) # определяет общее количество конкретного найденного слова
        #print (lenght)
        #for i in range(lenght):
        if res == None: continue #  Если не обнаружено слово
        else:
            k1 = res.start()
            k2 = res.end()
            content = content[:k1]+"//А//"+content[k1:k2]+"//А//"+content[k2:]
    print(content)
    return content
###############################################

content = open_read(path) # окрываем файл
content = set_checkpoints(content) # обрабатываем файл функцией set_checkpoints()

file = open(save, 'w') # сохраняем файл
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

P.S.
Я так понимаю тут дело заключается в методе `search()`, т.к. метод `search()` ищет по всей строке, но возвращает только первое найденное совпадение. Тут похоже нужно использовать метод `findall()`, т.к. этот метод возвращает список всех найденных совпадений. Но я не знаю, как в `findall()` реализовать установку чекпоинтов. Свойства `start()` и `end()` работают только в методе `search()`.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Откуда пробел появился в `//А// абрикос//А//`?

Comment: Упс. Сорян. Это я ошибся в тексте, когда создавал вопрос. Исправил

Comment: Бывает, я и предполагал что там ошибка :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужны тут регулярные выражения:

```
fruits = ['яблоко', 'банан', 'абрикос', 'апельсин', 'мандарин']

with open('input.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f_in:
    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            # Для удаления справа пустых символов: ' ', '\n', '\r', и т.п.
            line = line.rstrip()
            
            # Если фрукт есть в списке
            if line in fruits:
                f_out.write('//А//{}//А//\n'.format(line))
```

---

Если работать с текстом и через функцию:

```
FRUITS = ['яблоко', 'банан', 'абрикос', 'апельсин', 'мандарин']

def set_checkpoints(text: str) -> str:
    # В одну строку
    return '\n'.join(
        '//А//{}//А//'.format(line)
        for line in text.splitlines() if line in FRUITS
    )

with open('input.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.read()

# Обрабатываем файл функцией set_checkpoints()
content = set_checkpoints(content)

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Результат (`output.txt`):

```
//А//яблоко//А//
//А//банан//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//яблоко//А//
//А//апельсин//А//
//А//апельсин//А//
//А//мандарин//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
```

Answer (score 1):

Если планируется обрабатывать небольшие файлы (заведомо меньшие половины свободной оперативной памяти), то можно заменять текст без циклов:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

fruits = ['яблоко','банан','абрикос','апельсин','мандарин'] # массив ключевых слов
pref, suff = '//А//', '//А//'

text = Path(r'D:\temp\1.txt').read_text(encoding='utf-8')

pat = r'(\b)({})(\b)'.format('|'.join(fruits))
text = re.sub(pat, r'\1{}\2{}\3'.format(pref, suff), text)

Path(r'D:\temp\result.txt').write_text(text, encoding='utf-8')

# check
print(Path(r'D:\temp\result.txt').read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
```

результат:

```
//А//яблоко//А//
//А//банан//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//яблоко//А//
//А//апельсин//А//
//А//апельсин//А//
//А//мандарин//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
//А//абрикос//А//
```